# Natural relations between substitutions

Tags: ct.category-theory, type-theory

Consider two contexts $\Gamma,\Delta$ (from some background type theory), and substitutions $s_1,s_2:\Gamma\rightarrow \Delta$.  In the case of $1$-element contexts, we get that a substitution is simply a term in the $\lambda$-calculus; in that case, we know that the 'natural' relations between terms arise from $\beta$-reduction (and sometimes $\eta$-contraction, $\delta$-convertibility and $\alpha$-renaming).  For example, Robert Seely [conjectured](http://www.pps.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~mellies/mpri/mpri-ens/articles/seely-modeling-computations-a-2-categorical-framework.pdf) [that article claims a proof, but a full proof only came many years later] that if the contexts belong from some dependently typed theory, there is a correspondance with locally cartesian closed categories, where the $2$-cells are given exactly by rewrites engendered by $\beta$ and $\eta$.

My question is, in general, what are the general relations which are considered *natural* between substitutions $s_1,s_2:\Gamma\rightarrow\Delta$ ?

Since the category of contexts is the opposite of the category of theory presentations, it is fairly natural to conjecture that this will be related to morphisms of **theory interpretations**.  So, looking at $2$-categories as **CAT**-enriched categories, one finds some work on [categories of interpretations](http://igitur-archive.library.uu.nl/lg/2008-0403-201345/preprint228.pdf), but it is not clear to me that this is indeed the right direction to look into.

In particular (from my admittedly CS-biased point-of-view), I would have expected something which more closely resembles term-rewriting in some guise.  But maybe I am simply not recognizing that what is given above is a semantic counterpart to something more operational.